# hive xpath get array of certain type of elements

Tags: xpath, hive

I have an xml

```
<d><a><c>1</c><b>2</b><b>3</b></a></d>
```

I'm trying to return an array of `<b>`

```
[2,3]
```

without the `<c>`. I tried this way

```
select xpath('<d><a><c>1</c><b>2</b><b>3</b></a></d>', "//*[local-name()='a']/*/text()");
```

but got

```
[1,2,3]
```

I thought this `//*[local-name()='a']/b` would work, but it returns an empty array.
How would I get the result I want?

Comment: Are you sure `//*[local-name()='a']/b` returns an empty array? It returns the two b's for me in a different XML tool ([xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)).

Comment: @cho That's what I see in the terminal.

Comment: What about `//a/b/text()`?

Comment: @cho This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and easy as this:

```
//b/text()
```

I tested it and works.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select xpath('<d><a><c>1</c><b>2</b><b>3</b></a></d>', "//*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/text()");
```

EDIT

this also works

```
"//*[local-name()='b']/text()"
```